# Error with code when run in a loop but none when run outside a loop

Tags: matlab

Hi and thank you for viewing my question.

I have a large spreadsheet (over 650,000 rows) that I am trying to spit up into separate parts of a structure. I am trying to split it up by the values in one of the columns of which there is 1132 unique text values. The rest of the columns are numerical. I have created a matrix of the numerical values with 4 columns called 'SectionID_Matrix' and a cell array for the text column I want to split the data up by called 'ELR'. I am also trying to name the parts in the structure by the text value I have split them up by. My code is as follows:

```
ELR_list = unique (ELR);
[m,~]=size(ELR_list);
n = 1;
b = [];

for j = 1:m
x = strcmp(ELR_list(n), char(ELR));
b(:,1) = SectionID_Matrix(x(:,1),1);
b(:,2) = SectionID_Matrix(x(:,1),2);
b(:,3) = SectionID_Matrix(x(:,1),3);
b(:,4) = SectionID_Matrix(x(:,1),4);
t = char(ELR_list(n));
s.(t) = b;
n = n+1;
end

clearvars -except *ELR_list* *ELR* *SectionID_Matrix* *s*
```

When I run this code though I get an error saying 'Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch'. Error in Sorting_Out_Locations (line 10). b(:,1) = SectionID_Matrix(x(:,1),1);

This is confusing me because when I remove the for loop and manually change the value of n, it works perfectly fine giving me a matrix in the structure with all the rows that contain the nth text value with the name of the text value.

I understand the error is caused by attempting to assign more elements to a section of a matrix or vector than that section can hold but I don't understand where that is happening.

Is there an error in my code that is causing the for loop to fail? because from my limited understanding the loop should just keep going around increase n by 1 each time until it has gone through all of the unique ELR values.

This is my very first time on Matlab (so any pointer on my code are very appreciated) and have spend all afternoon trying to get this working but no amount of internet help or the matlab website is helping.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Start your debugging by either (1) setting a breakpoint inside the loop and examining the sizes of your variables on each iteration, or (2) go to the debug options and select "stop on errors/warnings"; then you can see what's happening in the debugger.

Comment: Didn't think about using the debugger. The below suggestions fixed the problem but I tried running it through the debugger so I could understand and hopefully reduce my further problems. The debugger was very helpful with seeing where the problem was occurring. Thank you for pointing this out to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the first time it runs through the loop, the size of the `b` matrix is set according to the number of `true` values in x.  The next time it runs through the loop, that may be a different size, so you get the mismatch.

You can just clear b at the end of each loop iteration with `b = []`

Comment: Thank you so much, worked perfectly, seems there are a lot of things I have to learn about matlab.

Answer (score 0):

The error `Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch` appears when you try to insert a matrix of a certain size into a matrix of a different size. For your code, it means that in the line

```
b(:,1) = SectionID_Matrix(x(:,1),1);
```

there is an attempted insertion of mismatching sizes: the size of `SectionID_Matrix(x(:,1),1)` and the size of `b(:,1)` are not the same. This is most likely because you only take certain values of each column of `SectionID_Matrix` using the logical indexing of `x`. To fix this you need the same logical indexing in `b`:

```
b(x(:,1),1) = SectionID_Matrix(x(:,1),1);
```

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly, I will remember this lesson for the rest of my matlab coding. Seems like a good habit to check this type of thing.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer. What I usually do, if this error shows up and it's not immediately clear why, is to use the debugger (as was suggested above) to stop on the line which causes the error and see what the sizes are on each side of the assignment command.